# type=range is not working with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working in ionic framework and using cordova plugin for mp3 player. 
Here is the code for the progress bar:
`<input type="range" ng-change="barChangePosition(this)" ng-model="position" name="seekbar" min="0" max="{{trackDuration}}">`.
[image]

In **controller.js**

```
timer = $interval(function() {
    $scope.trackDuration = $scope.audio.getDuration();
    $scope.audio.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
            if (position > -1) {
                $scope.tempPosition = position;
                $scope.position = position;
            }
        },
        function(e) {
            $scope.error = e;
        });

    }, 1000);
```

I want to change the position of progress bar with time. For the first time its playing and changing the positions perfectly. `{{tempPosition}}` and `{{position}}` both works fine. But if I click on that progress bar to change its position then `{{tempPosition}}` works fine but `{{position}}` as well as progress bar stopped changing with time(does't work).

```
{{position}}<br/>
{{tempPosition}}<br/>
```

What can I do for this. I have also tried with `$watch` but getting the same issue. I think I am missing something. Please help!

Comment: you don't need to use `name="seekbar"` when using angular,  and see if there are any errors in console.

Comment: Could you provide the barChangePosition() function ? You probably change a primitive var and loose the reference.

Comment: i don't understand why you are passing `this` to `ng-change="barChangePosition(this)`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/DnHR0SNy10LCkotn3IcR?p=preview Works good without ng-change. Pretty sure the issue is in this function.

Comment: `barChangePosition` is used to change the song timings. `$scope.barChangePosition = function(val){seekTo(val.position);}`  @JideobiBenedineOfomah & @Okazari

Comment: @Okazari .. I checked it. outside the ionic environment my codes are working.

Comment: @soosmca apply() could lead to a lot of performance issues. apply shoudn't be use within a classic full angular app.

Comment: @SaribanD'Cl This is pretty strange, could you try to reproduce the issue in the ionic environnement in a plunker ? (Here is an angular plunkr you can start with http://plnkr.co/edit/b8sxOLNgGKZ36oQDGJLM?p=preview)

Comment: not possible I think

Comment: @all I have posted the answer below. Please check it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved: I have to use `data.position`. 
Please check this link http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/working-with-ng-model-and-input-type-range/949

Here is the full code:

```
<input type="range" ng-model="data.position" name="seekbar" min="0" max="{{trackDuration}}">
```

**Controller.js**

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.controllerName = "MainController";
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.pos = 0;
    timer = $interval(function() {
       $scope.trackDuration = 50;
       $scope.data.pos ++;
    }, 1000);
});
```